# Split ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to have a split action bar for android where the search widget is at the top action bar and the rest of the icons are in the bottom using android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" is there a way to do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`splitActionBarWhenNarrow` is not supported by `Theme.Material` or the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport.

If you wish to stick with something based off of `Theme.Holo` for all devices, you are welcome to use `splitActionBarWhenNarrow`.

If you wish to use either `Theme.Material` or `appcompat-v7`, you will need to create your own "split action bar", by having a `Toolbar` at the bottom of the screen that you populate separately.

For example, [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Toolbar/SplitActionBar) uses a `Toolbar` on API Level 21+ devices along with `Theme.Material`, gracefully degrading to having everything be in the action bar on Android 4.x devices.

Comment: Thank you Commonware for your answer. I am using Holo, do you know if there's a way to do it without the toolbar?

Comment: @yaronbic: Then use `android:splitActionBarWhenNarrow="true"` on the `<activity>` or `<application>` in the manifest, as you have in your question.